# Odoo CSS styles break

Tags: css, odoo

All of a sudden, Odoo login screen is damaged and the CSS styling becomes a mess as shown in the snapshot.

Symptoms:

- This happens with certain databases, but when creating new database it doesn't happen.
- Doesn't appear as long as I'm working on the same browser, when changing browser the problem appears.

What I tried:

- I installed a fresh database and started installing modules one by one in order to see which one will crash, but nothing happened.

I'm using Odoo 11CE from the official docker image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart your Odoo server and check your log at Odoo startup to find a python import error or warning because that normally it's associated with a python error loading your odoo modules from the addons paths. Not need to be installed modules.

Also the same could be happening when your Odoo server it's trying to load another Odoo database that fails to load due to a different Odoo version or because the lack of modules loaded for that database

Answer (score 1):

This had happened to me many times, I usually solve it by just cleaning the cache/cookies of the browser and restarting the Odoo service.
In other note, i noticed this happening mostly when I log to different databases with the same browser without closing additional tabs with odoo pages loaded in or when I move from a different version all together without logging out from previous sessions.

Comment: I tried this several times without success. 
How could it happen with one database and doesn't happen with the other?

Comment: You could check the javascript console in the browser, there should be an error message or warning related to the failing styles.
Also, I exclusively work with a local enviroment over ubuntu 18, so this issue may be related to your docker setup but I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 0):

if someone need help in this case i resolve it see my log in odoo  after that delete in database ,

the line in the log is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rute' 9739bf1f391e10051ed840fef5b341f9351d0536

after that restart server  and change the number and do this many time and reove you problem.

```
delete FROM "public"."ir_attachment" WHERE "public"."ir_attachment"."store_fname"LIKE '%9739bf1f391e10051ed840fef5b341f9351d0536%'
```